# Why do some iOS apps lose NSUserDefaults data when running my app from xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, ios10

I started noticing this issue on iOS 10.2 where some apps like **whatsapp**, **forza**, **kodi**, lose some info and my best guess was `NSUserDefults` data.

1. **Whatsapp** logout from my account I should enter my phone number again to receive messages again
2. **Forza** restarts syncing
3. **Kodi** reshows its help info

Am I the only one or what ?

Comment: This is a problem with iOS And KeyChain values which are probably being used. not NSUserDefaults. Many apps are experiencing these bugs.

Comment: @Sneak OMG what a terrible bug. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: At the moment, nothing I can think of. If all these giants have this problem, Facebook, Google etc. I suspect they have tried plenty. Check this for more information: https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xcode+keychain+data+nil+random&*

Comment: @Sneak that's what it looks like. I have been reading on google this issue goes back to iOS 9.3 what a shame.

Comment: @Sneak I saw your link. everyone seems to be experiencing the same issue that's huge disappointment.